# Invocar uma função passando os argumentos dentro de $Scope não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho uma função num arquivo chamado "mapHelper.js" responsável por adicionar popups num mapa:

```
     function writeMarker(x,y,msg) {
     var muxiCoordinates = [x,y];
     var muxiMarkerMessage = msg;
     L.marker(muxiCoordinates).addTo(map).bindPopup(muxiMarkerMessage).openPopup();
     }
```

Um controller que permite ler os dados do banco de dados para $scope.markers.
Os dados são uma lista de coordenadas e mensagens "x,y,msg"

```
angular.module("app",[]);
angular.module("app").controller("appCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/markers').then(function (res) {
        console.log("Got the data");
        $scope.markers=res.data;
    });
});
```

A dúvida é: como invocar essa função passando os argumentos dentro de $Scope?

pensei em algo como:

```
    div(ng-repeat="marker in markers")
        script.
            writeMarker({{marker.x}},{{marker.y}},{{marker.msg}});
```

mas não funciona.

Comment: Não sei bem como é a tua aplicação, mas parece-me que dentro de `$http.get('/markers').then(function (res) {` podias fazer diretamente `res.data.forEach(marker => writeMarker(marker.x, marker.y, marker.msg));`. Podes testar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua intenção é exibir exatamente quando acontece o retorno do $http do angular, você pode passar no response mesmo.

```
angular.module("app",[]);
angular.module("app").controller("appCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/markers').then(function (res) {
        console.log("Got the data");
        for(var i = 0; i < resp.data.length; i++){
            var data = resp.data[i];
            writeMarker(data.x,data.y,data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Agora, se você quer usar dinamicamente essa função do javascript, você pode passar a função do javascript para um `scope` do angular, e aí sim usar com um `ng-click` ou coisa do tipo, como você pretendia fazer:

```
$scope.writeMarker = writeMarker;
```

Comment: Muito bom, Obrigada. Problema resolvido

Comment: Se a resposta solucionou seu problema, poderia seleciona-la como certo para ajudar futuros usuários? Obrigado!